# How can I include multiple graphics from the same pdf in my beamer?

Tags: graphics, pdf

I usually use

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{figure.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

To include a figure that is in a one-page .pdf file into my beamer presentation. Now I have a pdf with multiple pages. On some pages there are figures I would like to include at different spots in beamer. Can I do this directly from beamer or do I first need to split up the pdf file into multiple files addressed separately from TeX?

Using the above code will simply include the first page of the pdf; but what if I need, say, the second or third?

Comment: you can use `\includegraphics[page=3]{figure}` to insert page 3.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Awesome thanks